# find a value based on multiple conditions within a tolerance in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm looking for an identification procedure using Pandas to trace the movement of some objects.
I want to assign a value (ID) compared to previous frame (Time) for each group based on multiple conditions (X,Y,Z) being within a tolerance (X<0.5,Y<0.6,Z<0.7) and write it in place. Also, if the value is not available, give it a new value (Count) which restarts by Group.
Here is an example:

Before:

| Group | Time | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.0 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| A | 1.0 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 |
| B | 1.0 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 |
| A | 1.1 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.4 |
| A | 1.1 | 5.5 | 5.5 | 5.5 |
| B | 1.1 | 3.6 | 3.6 | 3.6 |

After

| Group | Time | X | Y | Z | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.0 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 1 |
| A | 1.0 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2.2 | 2 |
| B | 1.0 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 1 |
| A | 1.1 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 1 |
| A | 1.1 | 5.5 | 5.5 | 5.5 | 3 |
| B | 1.1 | 3.6 | 3.6 | 3.6 | 1 |

for clarification:
Row#4: X,Y,Z change is within the tolerance, hence same ID
Row#5: X,Y,Z change is NOT within the tolerance, hence new ID in Group A
Row#6: X,Y,Z change NOT within the tolerance, hence same ID

I think I can trace the movement of my objects only for one direction (Let's say X) using pd.merge_asof regardless of their group and time, and find their ID. My problems are: 1. considering the group and time, 2. assignment of new ID, 3. different tolerances.

```
df3=pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="X", direction="nearest", by=["Group"], tolerance=0.5)
```

Comment: yes it does. both should be evaluated. Let me clarify:
X, Y and Z are position. I want to trace the movement of dozens of objects. If movement in each frame is within the tolerance, they receive the same ID (Meaning that it is the same object of this group which moved). If their movement is not within the tolerance, they receive a different ID (Meaning that it is a different object in this group).

Comment: Their position. In the table, row #1 and row #4 are the same object because: 1. they belong to the same group, 2. the movement (X,Y,Z) is in the tolerance. Row #2 and row #5 are two different objects, because, although they belong to the same group (A), their positions are from from each other (X,Y,Z outside of tolerance)

Comment: you're right, I edited it! my bad!